# Insert and retrieve ByteArray from SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#

I have a 128-bit key that I want to store in a database. My code creates the key as `byte[16]` and the datatype in the database is `varbinary(16)`.

When I try to retrieve the byte array again from the db, I don't get the original values.

Here is my code:

```
byte[] test =  new byte[16]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};

SqlCommand myInsertCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test(test) VALUES(@Param)", myConnection);       
SqlParameter param = myInsertCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 16);
param.Value = test;

myInsertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataAdapter myAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select test from Test;", myConnection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
myAdapter1.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    char[] charArray = row["test"].ToString().ToCharArray();
}
```

For `charArray`, I get 0x0053, 0x0079,0x0073,0x0074, etc and also, the `charArray` is only 13 bytes long. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason you convert byte array to string than to char array?

Comment: ArsenMkrt is right, the cast to string is your problem.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: Upvote. You are totally right! I think I need to get some sleep. I don't know why on earth, I want to use charArray.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`row["Test"]` contains `byte[]`, so `row["Test"].ToString()` returns default `ToString` of `byte[]` type, which is `"System.Byte[]"`. After which you convert `System.Byte[]` and get that result

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    byte[] byteArray = (byte[])row["test"];
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Just after I posted that question, I changed the code to the byte[] cast. I feel very stupid now. haha. Thanks for the quick answer though!!

Comment: @Artemix: After he posted the answer, I tried to accept it, but the system was saying "wait 8 minutes" before I could accept the answer.