# Ms sql how to insert image to database

Tags: sql-server, image, insert

I have **Image Table.**

I want to test some images on database side.

**How can i insert image from my desktop to Image Table ?**

Image Table has Columns like below,

```
Id,

Image_Name

Image
```

Thanks.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952261/insert-and-retrieve-bytearray-from-sql-server-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [OPENROWSET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) (SQL-Server 2005+)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Files (FileName, [File])
SELECT 'MyPic.bmp' AS FileName, *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\MyPic.bmp', SINGLE_BLOB) AS [File]
```